# How to query match a split string in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to take a professional photograph

I want to query the above sentence and see if each word above 4 letters is contained within a list.

I want the output to be the words that match.

Ex: professional, photograph

I tried split + query + regex to no avail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(sum(--REGEXMATCH(filter(split(A1," "),len(split(A1," "))>3),TEXTJOIN("|",,list))))=counta(filter(split(A1," "),len(split(A1," "))>3))
```

with list = list of words, A1 the sentence

[image]

Comment: This is great because the output is TRUE, I forgot to mention in my description that I want the output to be the words that match. Ex: professional, photograph

Answer (score 2):

With Mike's help, I figured it out!

=FILTER(SPLIT(B3," "),LEN(SPLIT(B3," "))>4)

Thanks Mike!